# how to add 2 textfields togethers as int (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, int, uitextfield, addition

I am trying to convert 2 textfields to ints and then add them together. I would also like to print the sum in the log.

```
let jake = t3.text! + t4.text!
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert text into Int in **Swift** and an addition like we can do...

```
   //set before this condition Validation for Text field
    let sum = (Int(textFirst.text ?? "0")! + Int(textSecond.text ?? "0"))!
    print(sum) //Output here
```

---

```
  //MARK: - Text Field Delegate Method for Input validation
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
  {
    let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
  }
```

Comment: This code will crash if the user enters text that isn't a valid `Int`.

Comment: We need to set input `validation` only accept `Int` value. @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

```
let t3Value: Int? = Int(t3.text!)
let t4Value: Int? = Int(t4.text!)
let final = t3Value! + t4Value!
print("Sum \(final)")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't force-unwrap optional values. It will cause a crash.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    if let val1 = Int(t3.text!), let val2 = Int(t4.text!)
    {
        let sum = val1 + val2
        print(sum)
    }
```

Comment: Don't force-unwrap optional values. It will cause a crash.

Comment: It won't if the outlets are connected properly.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the outlets. The `text` property of the text field can be `nil` and you are force-unwrapping them.

Comment: Whenever you access the text property of a textField, it will always return an empty string if the textField is empty.

Comment: The `text` property of `UITextField` is declared as `String?`. It may be the empty string in most cases but it *can* be `nil` since it is optional.

Comment: Sure it can be, but I have used it multiple times and I always got an empty string.